# How to mock the FacesContext using JUnit?

Tags: oracle-adf

I am using JUnit 4,

I want to Mock the `FacesContext` instance, I am getting nullpointer error while writing test case for the method that contains `FacesContext` instance, Similarly DataBinding and `BindignContainer` .. etc..

My method in Util class:

```
public static String resolveUserPrincipal() {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); // here I am null
    ExternalContext ectx = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)ectx.getRequest();
    return request.getUserPrincipal().getName();
}
```

My TestCase method:

```
@Test
public void testResolveExpression() {
    JSFUtils utils = new JSFUtils();
    //utils.resolveExpression(null);
    System.out.println(utils.resolveUserPrincipal());
    System.out.println("============== "+FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
}
```

Thanks!